# Using a custom font with bold text in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have an app where I am setting the font for a UILabel programmatically as below

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:[fontSize intValue]]];
```

wherein `fontName` is a string type variable that hold font name such as "Helvetica"
and `fontSize` will hold the size of the font. This works fine for me.
Now I want to make this text "Bold" how can I do that?

```
boldSystemFontOfSize
```

works for system font. How can I achieve the same for user defined fonts ?

Thanks.

Comment: I notice some things when using custom fonts. I have a file named `MavenPro-Bold.ttf` but the font name I use to make it work has to be `MavenProBold`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `@"Helvetica-Bold"` as the fontName.

Comment: This appears to be simple approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
NSArray *arr = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"myFavoriteFont"];
NSString *fontName = [arr objectAtIndex:0]; //or [arr objectAtIndex:1], it depends
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:[fontSize intValue]]];
```

Comment: This worked for me- downloaded a font from Google Web fonts, and couldn't find the bold name. I printed out each in the loop and found the right name. for (NSString *fontname in arr){ NSLog(@"fontname: %@", fontname); }  UIFont *font = [UIFont fontwithname:@"[insert name]"];

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
fontName = @"myFavouriteFont-Bold";
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:[fontSize intValue]]];
```

By using the the method `fontWithName:size:`, you can set the font name with style. [Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says that the fontName is the fully specified name of the font and this name incorporates both the font family name and the specific style information for the font.